# Laravel Controller acrescentar conteudo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Sou novato e gostaria de uma ajuda, tenho um `controller` que realiza uma consulta.

***Controller***

```
$user = $this->user->find('1');    
view('index', compact('user'));
```

***View***

```
@forelse ($user as $u)    
    <h1>{{ $u->name }}</h1>    
@endforeach
```

Na `View` precisaria colocar algum campo extra exemplo: ativo, mais não gostaria de mexer no banco de dados apenas colocar um campo e acessar no

```
{{ $u->ativo }}
```

Espero que tenha sido claro.

---

Para esclarecer melhor...

o user foi apenas um exemplo, ao invés de passar mais um objeto para `View` no `Controller` gostaria de mudar esse objeto e incluir itens nele, vamos dizer que passo um `user` e um `post` ao invés de fazer um novo `foreach`.

Em invés:

```
view('index', compact('user'),compact('post'));
```

gostaria

```
view('index', compact('user'));
```

Observação: user ou outro nome apenas exemplo.

Ao invés:

***View***

```
<h1>{{ $user->name }}</h1>    

@forelse ($post as $u)    
    <h1>{{ $u->name }}</h1>    
@endforeach
```

isso:

```
@forelse ($user as $u)    
    <h1>{{ $u->name }}</h1>    
    <h1>{{ $u->Postname }}</h1>  
@endforeach
```

*Espero que fique melhor a explicação.*

Comment: Primeiro, o controller retornar um usuário, apenas um, não sei como conseguiu fazer um `foreach`, não ficou claro isso, e outra coisa que não ficou clara, qual é o valor correspondente para gerar um campo a mais onde não tenha relação com a sua base, isso o `Eloquent` faz, mas, ele precisa saber o valor, que seria um adição de campo calculado. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para esclarecer melhor, esta um link de algo parecido criando em array mais https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857855/10569172, ao invés de usar nome["nome"] gostaria tb nome->nome.. se possivel... obrigado

Comment: `Sidiclei`, você não explicou melhor, piorou (**kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk**) rapaz se quer unir varias objetos em um objeto, porque? Isso vai aumentar a complexidade, agora se você tiver relação entre elas o próprio `Framework Eloquent` faz isso para você, é só chamar a relação com o comando `with` que é o mais indicado por ser otimizado. Não adianta criar uma pergunta que não seja a sua realidade, crie conforme a sua necessidade, e não coloque exemplos fictícios que não te ajudam a esclarecer o seu problema, por exemplo `User` e `Post` pode ter relação, mas, eu não sei se é sua realidade.